# Is there an efficient algorithm to verify that a finite binary code is uniquely decodeable?

Tags: algorithms, information-theory, coding-theory

Is there an efficient algorithm to verify that a finite binary code is uniquely decodeable?

Say we have some finite alphabet of symbols $\mathcal{A}$ and some encoding for each symbol $C$. What is the fastest way to check if $C$ is uniquely decodable: i.e., there are no distinct strings $s_1$ and $s_2$ in $\mathcal{A}^+$ such that $C^+(s_1) = C^+(s_2)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is, although not trivial: [Sardinas–Patterson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardinas%E2%80%93Patterson_algorithm) (1953).